# how to send data from form in page to option tag in other page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I did a form by jotform site contains two pages or two forms I want to send data of username from newuser.php page to add to option tag in previllige.php page I write the js code right but when I enter the data and click add button the result still "please wait " only without send data to other page

there is the code of two pages first page: newuser.php and its code is:

```
$(function () {
            $("#btnQueryString").bind("click", function () {
                var url = "previliges.php?name="  + encodeURIComponent($("#addItem").val()) ;
             //   window.location.href = url;
                document.location.href = url;

          });
        });
<div id="cid_6" class="form-input">
          <input type="text" class=" form-textbox validate[required]" data-type="input-textbox" id="addItem" name="username" size="20" value="" />
        </div>
```

second page: previllige.php and code of it :

```
<script language="javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
    var url = document.location.href,
        params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'),
        data = {}, tmp;


        //alert(params);
        var a = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
        //alert(a);


          var opt = document.createElement("option");
        document.getElementById("lbldata").options.add(opt);
         opt.text = a;
         $("#lblData").append('<option>'+opt.text+'</option>');

        }
</script>

 <select class="form-dropdown validate[required]" style="width:150px" id="lbldata" name="username">
            <option value="">  </option>
            <option value="amal"> amal </option>

          </select>
```

Comment: `params = url.split('?')[1].split('&')` I don't think this works right. I only see 1 parameter being sent to the script, so you can't split on `&` unless for some reason your value contains the `&` symbol and some logic is occurring that we can't identify.

Comment: I test this code out of these pages in other project and worked but in this project not work

Comment: I did it anyway . thanks for replay .

Comment: possible duplicate of [send data from form in page to option tag in other page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19321346/send-data-from-form-in-page-to-option-tag-in-other-page) and [I want to send data from form in page to option tag in other page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322072/i-want-to-send-data-from-form-in-page-to-option-tag-in-other-page)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get why you are doing this:

```
var a = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
```

but I am assuming you want to extract the params from url, but what you are doing is extracting the whole url untill the letter next to the last equal sign, I don't know why you did this, but this might be the result why you're not getting the name correctly in the second page.
your `params` array in your code contains the real parameters, you should use it to set the value of `var a`

Comment: i try this code out of this page in other project and worked but in this project not work